# php to change select box option

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I am using php and trying to change a option using php my code looks like this:

```
<?php
$ProductName = 'test2';
?>

<select id="product" name="product" value=<? echo $ProductName; ?> >
   <option value="test1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="test2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="test3">Option 3</option>
   <option value="test4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

however the above does not change the option.

any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to something like this:

```
<select id="product" name="product" value="" >
    <option value="test1"<? if($ProductName == "test1") echo " selected"; ?>>Option 1</option>
    <option value="test2"<? if($ProductName == "test2") echo " selected"; ?>>Option 2</option>
    <option value="test3"<? if($ProductName == "test3") echo " selected"; ?>>Option 3</option>
    <option value="test4"<? if($ProductName == "test4") echo " selected"; ?>>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

but that would be good to have the values and names of options in an array and do this check in a loop

Comment: but I would suggest to use Tim's solution, it is very elegant and nice solution IMO

Answer (score 2):

There is a couple of ways to do this.  First off the HTML you are looking for is:

```
<option value="test2" selected="selected">Option 2</option>
```

I prefer the Javascript/jQuery method myself as it doesn't clutter the hell out of my code.  After the `select` HTML:

```
$("#product option[value='<?php echo $productName;?>']").attr('selected','selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `selected` attribute to the `<option>` element. You might consider something like this:

```
<?php
$options = array('test1' => 'Option 1',
                 'test2' => 'Option 2', ...);

$selected = 'test1';
?>

<select id="product" name="product">
   <?php foreach ($options as $value => $text): ?>
      <option value="<?=$value?>"<?=$value == $selected ? ' selected' : ''?>>
        <?=$text?>
      </option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: @edwardmp are you kidding? They were posted 2 minutes apart and it's a fairly 'standard' way of doing it. Besides, mine wont throw a notice when the $_GET array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

When using a selectbox, the correct HTML to do this would be something like this:

```
<select id="product" name="product">
   <option value="test1" selected>Option 1</option>
   <option value="test2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="test3">Option 3</option>
   <option value="test4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

So add the "selected" word at the end of the value you want to select.

In PHP you could do it like this easily:

```
<select id="product" name="product">
<?php
$options = array(1 => 'Option 1', 2 => 'Option 2', 3 => 'Option 3');
foreach ($options as $key => $value) { 
   echo '<option value="' . $key . '"' . ($key == $_GET["test"] ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . $value . '</option>';
} ?>
</select>
```

Comment: but I want to be able to change the value based on the php value?

Comment: then you need to modify that code to show up in the part where it says "Option 1". That is the 'value' that is displayed to the user.